# Is there a better way of allocating/copying shared_array

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a stream object which provide `GetBuffer()` and `GetBufferSize()` methods. The `GetBuffer` method returns a raw `uint8_t` pointer. I want to pass (by value) this buffer to another object which expects a `shared_array<uint8_t>`. I'm using boost, (which I am fairly new to), and this is what I came up with.

```
// relevant protos for a and b
void BClass::SetData(shared_array<uint8_t> data, size_t data_len);
uint8_t* AClass::GetBuffer(void);
size_t AClass::GetBufferSize(void);

AClass a;
BClass b;

shared_array<uint8_t> data = shared_array<uint8_t>(new uint8_t[a.GetBufferSize()]);
memcpy(data.get(), a.GetBuffer(), a.GetBufferSize());
b.SetData(data, a.GetBufferSize());
```

It feels like there should be something similar to boost's make_shared that could clean this up. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Boost 1.53` [we've got `make_shared` for arrays](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared_array.html#example). So your code could look like this:

```
shared_ptr<uint8_t[]> data = make_shared<uint8_t[]>(a.GetBufferSize());
```

Of course, then you'd need to change `BClass::SetData` signature, to accept `shared_ptr` instead of `shared_array`.

Comment: That removes the call to new, but the `memcpy` still needs to be done separately. Also, isn't arrays in shared_ptr new in 1.53? IIRC, we're using Boost 1.33

Comment: @benf Yes, it's a new feature in boost1.53. As for `memcpy`, you can use `std::copy`, but it doesn't matter in this case.